# Post three dimension array object with Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, post, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post a complex object which classes are defined at ASP.NET. 
It is an array of "Site" which contains an array of "Variable" which contains an array of "Source".

- It **works perfectly if third level array (Sources) has 1 elem or less**. Otherwise, it fails. (action controller is not called) Why?
- It **works perfectly with MVC 3**. It **fails with MVC 4**.  Why?

Ajax post call:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'FieldData/GetStiffKml',
     data: JSON.stringify({ sitesForStiff: sites }),
     datatype: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {  }
  });
```

Action method:

```
public ContentResult GetStiffKml(Site [] sitesForStiff){
   ...
}
```

Class structure:

```
public class Site
{
    public string SiteCode { get; set; }
    public List<Variable> Variables { get; set; } 
}

public class Variable
{
    public int VariableID { get; set; }
    public List<Source> Sources { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public int SourceID { get; set; }
    public int ValueCount { get; set; }
}
```